# How can I programatically replace the text node within a NodeList?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following HTML structure:

```html
<div id="container">
  <b>Hello</b>
  World
</div>
```

and I'd like to replace `World` with `Earth` like this:

```html
<div id="container">
  <b>Hello</b>
  Earth
</div>
```

I **don't** want to modify the `<b>Hello</b>` element at all.

I can grab the container like this:

```js
var el = document.querySelector("#container")
```

which has three element in [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), the last of which is a [`textNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text):

[image: childNodes]

Is there a way to replace the text in the last element without modifying the *entire* `innerHTML` or `innerText`?

```js
var el = document.querySelector("#container")

console.log(el.childNodes)
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <b>Hello</b>
  World
</div>
```

Comment: In your example `document.querySelector('#container').childNodes[2].nodeValue = 'Earth';` but you could iterate the NodeList looking for the appropriate node by type and value.